# Can't count the value with lambda

Tags: kotlin

Please help to understand why the value of clicks doesn't change. I started read "Kotlin in action" and now have more questions than answers (it's joke book is great, but I'm not)

I tried to set `clicks` before function, it was advice from book "kotlin in action", but the value of `var clicks` is always 0.

I have the following interface :

```
interface Button {
    fun onClick(function: () -> Unit)
}
```

And Kotlin file

```
fun main() {
    var clicks = 0

    fun tryToClickOnButton(button: Button): Int{
        button.onClick{println("UPP $clicks")}
        button.onClick{clicks++}
        button.onClick{println("UPP $clicks")}
        return clicks
    }

    class SpecialButton: Button{
        override fun onClick(function: () -> Unit) {
            println("AAAAAA $clicks")
        }
    }

    val button = object: Button {
        override fun onClick(function: () -> Unit) {
            println("BBBBB $clicks")
        }
    }

    println(tryToClickOnButton(button))

    println(tryToClickOnButton(object : Button{
        override fun onClick(function: () -> Unit) {
            println("CCCCCCC $clicks")
        }
    }))

    println(tryToClickOnButton(SpecialButton()))

}
```

Comment: I think what you're not calling onClick at any point in your code :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have created a callback that takes a function, but you never call that function.

Let's remove some code, to make the example simpler:

```
fun main() {
    var clicks = 0

    fun tryToClickOnButton(button: Button): Int {
        button.onClick { println("UPP $clicks") }
        button.onClick { clicks++ }
        button.onClick { println("UPP $clicks") }
        return clicks
    }

    val button = object : Button {
        override fun onClick(function: () -> Unit) {
            println("BBBBB $clicks")
        }
    }

    println(tryToClickOnButton(button))
}
```

You can see that in your `Button`'s `onClick` callback, you accept an argument called `function` of type "function", but you never use it. Because of that, you'll never print "UPP ${clicks}" and you'll never increment `clicks` value.

To solve the issue, you simply need to call `function`, like this:

```
fun main() {
    var clicks = 0

    fun tryToClickOnButton(button: Button): Int {
        button.onClick { println("UPP $clicks") }
        button.onClick { clicks++ }
        button.onClick { println("UPP $clicks") }
        return clicks
    }

    val button = object : Button {
        override fun onClick(function: () -> Unit) {
            println("BBBBB $clicks")
            function() // this was missing
        }
    }

    println(tryToClickOnButton(button))
}
```

That code prints:

```
BBBBB 0
UPP 0
BBBBB 0
BBBBB 1
UPP 1
1
```